# Fit wrapper table on mobile device

Tags: html, css

How can I correct the code here so that when a user opens on a Mobile device, it opens to 100% of the page, and the text is left aligned on both sides i.e under the Package heading and the Ticket heading

It is laid out as is because there is direct correlation between each adjacent option i.e. Package - Convenience is adjacent to Ticket - Inconvenience

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2% auto;
}

.hgrp {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(11, 77, 122, 0.7);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
.hgrp h2 {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.hgrp h3 {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.hgrp::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-top: 2px dashed #fff;
  width: 300px;
}

li:last-child span::after {
  display: none;
}

.pro, .cons {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.pro {
  background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.7);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.cons {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 280px;
  }
}

  </style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>table pro&cons -flat</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#002E5D">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="hgrp">
            <h2>Package</h2>
            <h3>VS</h3>
            <h2>Tickets</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pro">
            <ul>
<li><span>All-inclusive inc Hotels</span></li></br>
<li><span>All WWE events included</span></li></br>
<li><span>Commemorative Chair with most packages</span></li></br>
<li><span>WWE provide the choices</span></li></br>
<li><span>Convenience</span></li></br>
<li><span>Ease of Use</span></li></br>
<li><span>Peace of mind that everything’s done</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>Pay all the package money at once</span></li></br>
<li><span>Single Transaction Purchase</span></li></br>
<li><span>Less stressful buying in one Transaction</span></li></br>
<li><span>Only one day of stress, and all WWE </br>events are all sorted there and then</span></li></br>
<li><span>Excitement of opening the Package</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>WWE do the planning for you</span></li></br>
<li><span>WWE provide the Package</span></li></br>
<li><span>Custom to WWE's preferences</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>WWE provide the choices regardless </br>of your budget</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>No Flexibility with Hotels</span></li></br>
<li><span>Hotel cost are far higher than market value</span></li></br>
<li><span>More Expensive (Pending on preference)</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>WWE Provide the cost</span></li></br>
<li><span>You know cost in advance</span></li></br>
<li><span>Packages are overpriced! and don't </br>include your whole holiday spending</span></li></br>
<li><span>Not having to use Ticketmaster</span></li></br>
<li><span></br>WWE don’t get involved here</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>Ruch for Packages (One Time)</span></li></br>
<li><span>Guaranteed Tickets to all WWE events</span></li></br>
<li><span>Not receiving tickets till later </span></li></br>
<li><span>All tickets on sale on same day</span></li></br>
<li><span>Not time-consuming</span></li></br>
<li><span>No risk of not getting event tickets</span></li></br>
<li><span>No reseller required</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>WWE accept all global locations</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>No Flexibility with Seating</span></li></br>
<li><span>Better seats if you get the top package</span></li></br>
<li><span>Don’t get to pick your seat</span></li></br>
<li><span>Guaranteed Good Seats</span></li></br>
<li><span>Better chances of getting Front Row</span></li></br>
<li><span>Seats may not reflect the price you're paying</span></li></br>
<li><span></br>You're stuck with WWE's schedule</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span>You will pay for all events regardless</span></li></br>
<li><span>WWE Pick the seats for you</span></li></br>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cons">
            <ul>
              <li><span> Purchase everything separately </span></li></br>
<li><span> Purchase WWE Tickets separately </span></li></br>
<li><span> Chair only with Top Tier Tickets </span></li></br>
<li><span> More choice available </span></li></br>
<li><span> Inconvenience </span></li></br>
<li><span> Ticketmaster can be unbearable to use </span></li></br>
<li><span> Constantly thinking about when tickets </br>are on sale and WHAT IF's </span></li></br>
<li><span> Pay when Tickets go on-sale only </span></li></br>
<li><span> Multiple transactions per each event </span></li></br>
<li><span> More stressful buying separately </span></li></br>
<li><span> Multiple days and pre-days of stress</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span> You receive Tickets straight away and know </br>your seat </span></li></br>
<li><span> You do the planning and work yourself </span></li></br>
<li><span> You create your own Package </span></li></br>
<li><span> More customized to your own preference when </br>all things are considered </span></li></br>
<li><span> You Can tailor your experience to personal </br>preferences and budget. </br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span> Choose what hotels you want </span></li></br>
<li><span> You can book hotels cheap if you look carefully </span></li></br>
<li><span> Overall Cheaper doing it all </br>separate (Pending on preference) </span></li></br>
<li><span> You can spread the cost and Budget </span></li></br>
<li><span> Might go over budget </span></li></br>
<li><span> Ticket prices are bearable</br></br></span></li></br>
<li><span> Ticketmaster shutting you out </span></li></br>
<li><span> Risk of not getting tickets at a </br>reasonable price for all non-Mania</br> WWE events if not quick enough </span></li></br>
<li><span> Rush for Tickets (Multiple Times) </span></li></br>
<li><span> Might Sell-out </span></li></br>
<li><span> Having tickets straight away </span></li></br>
<li><span> Multiple on sale dates and pre-sales </span></li></br>
<li><span> Time-consuming </span></li></br>
<li><span> Risk of missing out on Tickets (sold-out etc) </span></li></br>
<li><span> Might need to use a re-seller </br>i.e. Stubhub or equivalent </span></li></br>
<li><span> Not always being able to purchase the tickets </br>first time because of buying outside USA </span></li></br>
<li><span> Flexibility to choose your own seating </span></li></br>
<li><span> Choose different ticket levels(Better or worse) </span></li></br>
<li><span> Select your own seat section </span></li></br>
<li><span> You might not get seats at all </span></li></br>
<li><span> Harder chance of getting floor level </span></li></br>
<li><span> Better seat selection options </span></li></br>
<li><span> You may want to see other shows </br>besides WWE’s offerings </br>during WrestleMania weekend. </span></li></br>
<li><span> You might not want to attend all WWE events </span></li></br>
<li><span> You can pick the seat and events you want </span></li></br>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It currently looks like [image]

Comment: Remove the fixed `width: 300px` on your `::after` element. That is ultimately what is making it so those LIs don't shrink down.

Comment: You also want to change `.wrapper`'s width under `414px` to `100%`.